# Why hamachi time-outs after 5 minutes or so?

Tags: networking, internet, vpn, internet-connection

I installed **Hamachi** and **Hamachi-GUI**, on both my girlfriend's PC and Netbook. 
After 5 minutes or so (even if i keep using it during that time) it loses its online-connection. I have to go offline, then online again in order to see my ip again.

If i don't and I ping my IP, it says `Host unreachable`. Now when i connect with my Mac from the office the problem doesn't exist, so i wouldn't say it is a problem of my "Hamachi (server) installation", and i am tempted to say, it is a problem of my girlfriend's connection, since it happens from her home, and we haven't tried yet to connect from another home with her setup.

I followed these [instructions](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=135036). What would you say?!

Answer (score 1):

Just solved creating a config file in hamachi directory (where the other files client.pub, client.pri, etc. are located) and just writing

```
KeepAlive 100
```

Then I restarted hamachi and it all worked (I discovered today that even from the office the connection timed-out after 10 minutes, so something happened during the week-end that screwed things a bit).

Thanks anyway!!

Comment: Hamachi works so weakly, in my experience!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue when using the Haguichi-GUI for Hamachi, it periodically lost connection with Hamachi running in the background. A quick look at `sudo systemctl status logmein-hamachi` revealed that the service was paused. Running

```
sudo systemctl restart logmein-hamachi
```

fixed the issue and Hamachi hasn't paused since, even after computer reboots.